# What is the different semantic of existential and universal qualifier between classical and intuitionistic logic?

Tags: logic

Take the semantic definition of existential and universal qualifier outlined [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_order_logic#Evaluation_of_truth_values)

Is that valid for classical or intuitionistic logic? Or is it a general definition?

---

Take the following sentence:

"It exists a man that, if he owns an hat, then all mans own an hat"

Take $C(x)$ is the predicate:
"Man $x$ owns an hat"

than the sentence can be formally written as follow:

$\exists x(C(x) \rightarrow \forall xC(x)) $

How can that sentence be semantically interpreted using the initial definition of existential and universal qualifier?

Comment: Are you asking about mathematical structures, like models of (classical) first order logic or about the philosophical/conceptual differences? In the former case you should look up realizability models, Kripke models or topological models. In the latter case, the Brower Heyting Kolmogorov interpretation of intuitionistic logic.

Comment: Where have you looked? What particular type of definition are you looking for?

Comment: @CarlMummert: I've looked on Wikipedia ( [First order logic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#First-order_structures) ) since now it is my only available source.

Comment: @aws: By now might be sufficient the conceptual difference.

Answer (score 6):

The semantic definitions you linked to in the first line of the question would be acceptable intuitionistically as well as classically, **but** an intuitionist would take "there exists an evaluation $\mu'$" to mean that one can actually exhibit an appropriate $\mu'$.  In other words, these definitions are intuitionistically acceptable in the context of an intuitionistic meta-theory.

From a philosophical viewpoint, one usually regards intuitionistic logic as differing from classical logic mainly in the interpretations of $\lor$ and $\exists$.  Intuitionism requires, for the assertion of $\phi\lor\psi$ or of $\exists x\,\phi(x)$, that one can (at least in principle) assert one of the disjuncts (in the case of $\lor$) or one specific instance (in the case of $\exists$). Because intuitionistic reasoning respects these requirements, proofs in intuitionistic systems often have far clearer computational content than proofs in similar classical systems.

Answer (score 3):

One example is that in intuitionistic logic the usual De Morgan's laws do not hold (that is, only three out of four implications are true, e.g. see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/120187/26306)), in particular

$$\neg(p \land q)\quad \text{ does not imply }\quad \neg p \lor \neg q.$$

Similarly

$$\neg \forall x. P(x) \quad \text{ does not imply } \quad \exists x. \neg P(x).$$

I hope it helps ;-)

**Edit:** Removed some false claims.

Comment: Sorry for such a late reply. I don't see how to prove ¬(¬p ∨ ¬q) ⇒ p ∧ q. It looks as if one would need to manufacture proofs of p and q out of thin air (i.e by contradiction). I can prove ¬p ∧ ¬q ⇔ ¬(q ∨ p), though. I can also prove (∀x. ¬(P x)) ⇔ ¬(∃x. P x).

Comment: @JamesWood You can use Heyting algebras to show it is wrong (like [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/693881/26306)). It should have been $$\neg (p \land q) \iff \neg\neg(\neg p \lor \neg q),$$ I have no idea what made me write such nonsense, sorry for that.

Answer (score 2):

I think there's quite a nice explanation in the SEP article on [constructive mathematics](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/mathematics-constructive/), in particular the section on [the constructive interpretation of logic](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/mathematics-constructive/#2). It's best not to look at existential and universal quantifiers in isolation, but look at the interpretation as a whole, especially since disjunction and implication are also very important.

Since there are already good explanations around, I'll just give a quick example of when existential quantification is different in classical and intuitionistic logic:

Let $P$ be any proposition. For instance, take it to be some unproved conjecture eg the twin prime conjecture. In classical logic we can easily show that there is some number $n$ such that either $n$ is $0$ and $P$ is false or $n$ is $1$ and $P$ is true, by applying an instance of excluded middle $P \vee \neg P$. In intuitionistic logic you can't do this in general because you need to supply an actual witness for $n$. In particular you need to know whether $n$ is $0$ or $1$, which you can't do without either proving or disproving $P$.

Comment: Taking P is the twin prime conjecture, what does $n$ stand for?

Comment: In classical logic $n$ is defined to be $1$ if there are infinitely many twin primes or $0$ if there are not infinitely many. So it is probably equal to $1$.

Comment: There's actually another classic example that you might find much clearer: there exist $a$ and $b$ irrational such that $a^b$ is rational. It's in the introduction of the article I linked to (http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/mathematics-constructive/#1).