# Propositional Logic Proof of DeMorgan's Law

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction, formal-proofs

This problem was recently posed to me that I prove it.

$\vdash (A \land B ) \iff \neg(\neg A \lor \neg B) $

We are only allowed to use derivation rules. It is obviously just the statement of DeMorgan's law. Somehow we have to use biconditional introduction, but when I assume $A \land B$ I can't arrive at $\neg(\neg A \lor \neg B)$.

Thank you in advance.

We are allowed to use the introduction and elimination of the following operators: $\neg, \land, \lor, \Rightarrow \iff$

No other rules are allowed.

Comment: What do you mean by "derivation rules"?

Comment: wow I didnt include that in my post.

We are only allowed to use the following rules: Conjunction Introduction/Elimination, Disjunction Introduction/Elimination, Conditional Introduction/Elimination, Bicondintional Introduction/Elimination, and negation introduction and elimination.

Comment: You must split the proof on two sub-proofs: $(A \land B) \to \lnot (\lnot A \lor \lnot B)$ and $\lnot (\lnot A \lor \lnot B) \to (A \land B)$ and after use [Biconditional-intro rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biconditional_introduction).

Comment: @agentnola Thanks for the list of rules, but there are *many* different proof systems, and even if they use this same list of names, there are still differences between different systems how those rules are actually implemented. That is, rules like 'Negation Elimination' or 'Biconditional introduction' can be defined differently between different proof systems.  Also, does your system use explicit subproofs?  Is there any way you could upload an image or have a link to a webpage, or provide a book reference, so it's cleas what *exactly* those rules are?

Comment: @Bram28 We dont really have a complete list. Yes, we have explicit subproofs. I would upload a page or something with all of our rules, but our class no longer uses our text book...

Comment: @agentnola Do you know the name of the book? I have a bunch on my shelf ...

Comment: @Bram28 the book is called _Symbolic Logic_ by David W. Agler, published in 2013

Comment: @agentnola Great!  I don't have the book but found the relevant chapter online. I'll post a proof soon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, that's a pretty nasty proof ... especially the first half.  I doubt you're going to learn any logical reasoning from it, but hey!

$\def\fitch#1#2{\begin{array}{|l}#1 \\ \hline #2\end{array}}$

$\fitch{}{
\fitch{1. A \land B \quad A}{
\fitch{2. \neg A \lor \neg B \quad A}{
\fitch{3. \neg A \quad \quad A}{
\fitch{4. A \land B \quad A}{
5. A \quad \land E, 4\\
6.\neg A \quad R, 3
}\\
7. \neg(A \land B) \quad \neg I, 4-6}\\
\fitch{8. \neg B \quad \quad A}{
\fitch{9. A \land B \quad A}{
10. B \quad \land E, 10\\
11.\neg B \quad R, 8
}\\
12. \neg(A \land B) \quad \neg I, 4-6
}\\
13. \neg(A \land B) \quad \lor E, \ 2,3-7,8-12\\
14. A \land B \quad R,1
}\\
15. \neg (\neg A \lor \neg B) \quad \neg I, 2-14}\\
\fitch{
16. \neg (\neg A \lor \neg B) \quad A}{
\fitch{
17. \neg A \quad A}{
18. \neg A \lor \neg B \quad \lor I, 17\\
19. \neg (\neg A \lor \neg B) \quad R, 16
}\\
20. A \quad \neg E, 17-19\\
\fitch{
21. \neg B \quad A}{
22. \neg A \lor \neg B \quad \lor I, 21\\
23. \neg (\neg A \lor \neg B) \quad R, 16
}\\
24. B \quad \neg E, 21-23\\
25. A \land B \quad \land I, 20,24
}\\
26. (A \land B ) \leftrightarrow \neg (\neg A \lor \neg B) \quad \leftrightarrow I, \ 1-15-16-25
}$

Answer (score 1):

I dont know why anyone would like or need to use biconditional introduction to do this. It seems like a very far workaround. Here is a sketch of what you need to do in order to get you going.

When proving $\neg (\neg A \vee \neg B)$ from $A \wedge B$, assume $\neg A\vee \neg B$ and try to arrive at a contradictions. This should be quite straight forward by using $\vee-$elimination and the fact that $A\wedge B$ is already known.

To show $A\wedge B$ from $\neg (\neg A \vee \neg B)$, first assume $\neg A$ then get a contradiction using $\vee-$elimination thus $A$ has to hold secondly just do the same thing for B and thus we arrive at both $A$ and $B$ as conclusions.

Comment: You first prove $\vdash \neg (\neg A\vee \neg B)\to (A\wedge B)$ and $\vdash (A\wedge B)\to\neg(\neg A\vee\neg B)$. This enables you to *then* use *biconditional introduction* ("$\sf\leftrightarrow I$") to obtain $\vdash (A\wedge B)\mathop{\leftrightarrow}\neg(\neg A\vee\neg B)$ .  $$\dfrac{{\vdash \phi\to \psi\\\vdash \psi\to \phi}}{\vdash \phi\mathop{\leftrightarrow} \psi}{\small\sf \leftrightarrow I}$$

Comment: Ah, uh... yeah, sure...

Answer (score 1):

Here's the full proof in a calculus called $C_R$, the precise implementation of the rules may vary for your calculus, though.

In $C_R$ you need biconditation introduction, it's the last step in proving a biconditional statement (after you have proved both directions separately). Also I use Reductio Ad Absurdum for the sake of simplicity of the proof.

$[1] \qquad    1 \quad  \neg(\neg A \vee\neg B) \qquad \qquad \qquad  \quad  $A

$[2] \qquad    2 \quad \neg A  \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad\qquad \quad   $A

$[2] \qquad 3 \quad \neg A \vee \neg B  \qquad \qquad \quad \qquad  \quad  \vee I. 2$

$[1]\qquad    4 \quad  A   \qquad  \qquad  \qquad \quad \quad\qquad  \quad   $RAA, 1,3,2

$[5]\qquad     5 \quad  \neg B  \qquad  \qquad  \qquad  \qquad \qquad   \quad $A

$[5] \qquad      6 \quad  \neg A \vee \neg B \qquad  \qquad  \qquad  \qquad  \vee Int 5$

$[1]\qquad     7 \quad  B  \qquad  \qquad  \qquad  \qquad  \qquad  \quad   $RAA 1,6,5

$[1]\qquad     8 \quad  A \wedge  B  \qquad  \qquad  \qquad  \qquad  \quad \wedge Int 4,7$

$[]\quad \qquad   9 \quad   \neg(\neg A \wedge \neg B) \Rightarrow A \wedge B  \quad   \quad  \Rightarrow Int 8,1$

$[10]\qquad      10 \quad   A \wedge  B\qquad  \qquad  \qquad  \qquad  \quad  $A

$[11] \qquad      11\quad   \neg A \vee \neg B  \qquad  \qquad  \qquad  \qquad  $A

$[10]\qquad     12 \quad    A  \qquad  \qquad  \qquad  \qquad  \qquad  \quad \wedge E 10$

$[10]\qquad     13 \quad    B  \qquad  \qquad  \qquad  \qquad  \qquad  \quad \wedge E 10$

$[10,11] \quad    14 \quad   \neg B  \qquad  \qquad  \qquad  \qquad  \qquad  \vee E 11,12$

$[10] \qquad     15 \quad    \neg (\neg A \vee \neg B)   \qquad  \qquad  \qquad  \quad $RAA 13,14,11

$[] \qquad  \quad    16 \quad A\wedge B \Rightarrow \neg (\neg A \vee \neg B)  \qquad\Rightarrow I 15,11$

$[]\qquad \quad    17 \quad A\wedge B  \Leftrightarrow \neg (\neg A \vee \neg B)  \qquad \Leftrightarrow I 9,16$

I am not sure but I think the calculus is from the book: $\textit{Allen, Colin, and Michael Hand. Logic primer. Mit Press, 2001}$.

Comment: RAA is probably one of (or maybe both) the Negation Introduction/Elimination rules

Answer (score 0):

The OP asks for a proof of DeMorgan's laws with the following restriction:

> We are allowed to use the introduction and elimination of the following operators: ¬,∧,∨,⇒⟺
>
> No other rules are allowed.

Essentially we are restricted to intuitionistic natural deduction inference rules. However, according to the answers to this question [Do De Morgan's laws hold in propositional intuitionistic logic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/120187/312852), not all of the four DeMorgan's laws can be shown using intuitionistic logic.

Here is an attempt at a proof that cannot be finished because I am not allowed to use double negation elimination nor indirect proof which I would have used on lines 15 and 19. All I can derive is $\neg \neg A \land \neg \neg B$ which I derive as a compromise on line 20:

[image]

---

Kevin Klement's JavaScript/PHP Fitch-style natural deduction proof editor and checker http://proofs.openlogicproject.org/

Comment: See Bram28's answer.  The rule called "negation elimination" in *Symbolic Logic* by David W. Agler, is known as "indirect proof (IP)" in the Open Logic Projects' proof checker.

Comment: @GrahamKemp I don't think Bram28's answer is correct. Lines 20 and 24 reference incorrectly $\neg E$. That rule derives the absurdity symbol. See my lines 14 and 18. What Bram28 is using is called indirect proof as you mention. That implies double negation elimination which cannot be derived using the permitted inference rules for this question.

Comment: As pointed out, different texts define the rules differently.  The OP's text does not use the absurdity symbol, just contrary statements. What it *calls* negation elimination is: when assumption of a negative derives contradictory statements, you may discharge the assumption to infer the positive.

Comment: @GrahamKemp The OP was given the problem with a constraint to use only certain rules. That is all. The details of those rules were not specified. My suspicion is that the OP was given the problem to show something that could not be shown with intuitionistic rules.

Comment: Yes, but just listing the *name* of the rules is often not sufficient, since different systems use *the same names for different rules*. There isn't a single standard (and that is annoying).  When quizzed on this in *the comments*, the OP clarified that the book was David W. Agler's *Symbolic Logic: Semantics, Syntax, and Proof*.

Comment: So your proof isn't wrong; it just uses a different system to the OP's preference.  That is just something to be aware of when answering questions.

Comment: @FrankHubeny  I followed the rules from Agler's book:  $\neg \ E$ is when you have a subproof that assumes something of the form $\neg \phi$, and ends up with both $\psi$ and $\neg \psi$ for some statement $\psi$ later on in that subproof ... you can now infer $\phi$ after the subproof. I really think my proof is correct.