# Natural Deduction $(\phi \wedge \psi) \to \chi \vdash (\phi \to \chi) \vee (\psi \to \chi)$

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, natural-deduction, formal-proofs

I have to proof the following using natural deduction:  $(\phi \wedge \psi) \to \chi \vdash (\phi \to \chi )\vee (\psi \to \chi)$. I want to try to do this without using morgan's laws or anything like that - just the rules for introducing/eliminating the symbols. Can anyone help to get me started?

Comment: Isn't what you want to prove false? Take $\phi$ is divisibilty by $2$, $\psi$ divisibility by $3$ and $\chi$ divisibility by $6$, in $\Bbb N$ as a model. Then the left hand holds but neither implication holds.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I see what you mean - but creating a truth table for both sides works, they are both the same. So no I am pretty sure the statement is true

Comment: it isn’t about truth tables.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Ok this is interesting, because I do agree with what you are saying. How come that the truth tables are the same, but the statement is false? Or am I just working on a kind of logic where that doesn't matter

Comment: But the formula **is** a tautology; thus, it must be provable.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma But for any number $n$ if it is not divisible by 6 one of the following must occur. Either it is not divisible by 2, in which case $\phi \to \chi$ holds, or it is not divisible by 3, in which case $\psi \to \chi$ holds.

Comment: It’s not true in intuitionism so we need negation based rules like RAA or TND.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Improved proof, thanks to comments received.*

The proof uses Double Negation rule: thus, it is not intuitionistically valid.

1. $(\phi \wedge \psi) \to \chi$ --- premise
2. $\lnot [(\phi \to \chi )\vee (\psi \to \chi)]$ --- assumption [a]
3. $\phi$ --- asumption [b]
4. $\psi$ --- assumption [c]
5. $(\phi \wedge \psi)$ --- from 3) and 4) by $\land$intro
6. $\chi$ --- using 5) and 1) by $\to$-elim
7. $(\psi \to \chi)$ --- from 4) and 6), discharging [c]
8. $\bot$ --- from 7) using $\lor$-intro and 2)
9. $\chi$ --- from 8) using EFQ
10. $(\phi \to \chi)$ --- from 3) and 9), discharging [b]

Now we have again a contradiction with 2) and we conclude by DN with:

> $(\phi \to \chi )\vee (\psi \to \chi)$ --- discharging [a].

Comment: +1. By the way, lines 5, 7, 8 are superfluous.

Comment: Indeed. You may immediately derive $\chi$ on assuming $\phi$ and $\psi$ (as per line 6), without any need to further assume $\neg\chi$.

Comment: You discharge them as you did, @MauroALEGRANZA  . The proof is otherwise okay, it just does not need lines 5, 7, and 8.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, the formula is true (in fact, the converse also holds). This you have already seen in your truth table. However, you ask to prove it without De Morgan's laws, and that is simply impossible. The reason is that it is not a tautology in intuitionistic logic. Put differently: you will need some instance of double negation elimination (or proof by contradiction).

I wrote an answer about this for a more specific case [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3753203/is-law-of-excluded-middle-necessary-in-this-proof/3753248#3753248). They ask about $\neg(P \wedge Q) \to (\neg P \vee \neg Q)$. So setting $\phi = P$, $\psi = Q$ and $\chi = \bot$ we see that that really is a special case of what you are asking about.

Comment: Or, for a Kripke frame to show it's not a tautology in intuitionistic logic: let $K := \{ 0, 1, 1', 2 \}$ with $0 < 1 < 2$, $0 < 1' < 2$.  And on 0 nothing is true; on 1 just $\phi$ is true; on $1'$ just $\psi$ is true; and on 2, all of $\phi, \psi, \chi$ are true.